# how to fill the value of the column based on the condition of another column?

Tags: r

I am trying to fill the value of pca.data$Type with 'DMSO' if the 'DMSO' is present in the column of pca.data$sample in R.

```r
pca.data$Type[pca.data$sample %in% "DMSO"]='DMSO'
```

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

```
pca.data$Type[grep("DMSO", pca.data$sample)] = "DMSO"
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do that. In addition to the base R method already proposed, you can use `data.table` or `dplyr`

## data.table

Use conditional replacement with the `:=` (update by reference)

```r
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(pca.data)
dt[grepl("DMSO", get('sample')), Type := "DMSO"]
```

The above snippet makes assignment. If you want to visualize the output : `dt[]`

## dplyr

You might use `dplyr::if_else` in this case

```r
pca.data %>% dplyr::mutate(Type = if_else(grepl("DMSO", sample), 'DMSO', sample)
```